# Adding PrimeFaces notificationBar makes my code stop working

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, ejb

I've got a weird problem with PrimeFaces' NotificationBar.

My code is working but, adding a NotificationBar will make it act in a strange way!

I'm showing data from a Session Bean in a DataTable.
Everything's fine but, as soon as I add this NotificationBar, datatable becomes empty and no content is fetched :/

Here's some code :

```
<!-- NOTIFICATION BAR headerMain.xhtml -->
    <h:form>
        <pou:poll autoStart="#{loginBean.logged}" global="false" interval="5" oncomplete="notificationBar.toggle()" update=":notificationBar"/>
    </h:form>


    <pou:notificationBar effect="slide" id="notificationBar" rendered="#{messagesBean.checkDaNotificare()}" widgetVar="notificationBar">                            
        <h:outputLink value="./faces/messaggi.xhtml">                                        
            <h:outputText value="Hai 1 messaggio da leggere" rendered="#{messagesBean.daNotificare==1}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Hai #{messagesBean.daNotificare} messaggi da leggere" rendered="#{messagesBean.daNotificare > 1}"/>
        </h:outputLink> 
    </pou:notificationBar>
```

_

```
<!-- DATATABLE IN messaggi.xhtml -->
<pou:dataTable editable="false" id="conversationList" resizableColumns="false" rowKey="#{conversazione}" selection="#{messagesBean.destinatario}" selectionMode="single" value="#{messagesBean.listaConversazioni}" var="conversazione" widgetVar="conversationList" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="20">
                        <pou:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="conversationDialog.show()" update=":conversationDialog, :menuPanel"/>
                        <pou:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <div style="padding-left: 45%">
                                    <h:outputText value="Conversazioni"/>                                                                                                                            
                                    <h:form>
                                        <pou:commandButton value="+" onclick="newMessageDialog.show()" style="margin-left: 67%"/>
                                    </h:form>
                                </div>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{conversazione.username}"/>
                        </pou:column>
                    </pou:dataTable>
```

_

```
//Method used by NotificationBar to see if it has to be rendered
public boolean checkDaNotificare() {
    System.err.println(daNotificare);
    daNotificare = 0; //Riazzero, quelli precedenti li avrò già notificati
    for (Messaggio m : getMessaggiDaLeggere()) {
        System.err.println("Controllo " + m);
        if (!messaggiNotificati.contains(m)) { //Conto i messaggi da notificare, che sono quelli da leggere meno quelli già notificati
            System.err.println("___Non l'avevo ancora notificato!");
            daNotificare++;
            messaggiNotificati.add(m);
        }
    }
    return (daNotificare > 0);
}
```

_

```
//Method used by the datatable to fetch data
public List<Utente> getListaConversazioni() {
    listaConversazioni = messageManager.getUtentiConversazioni(utente);
    return listaConversazioni;
}

/**
 * PostConstruct method to initialize things
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    listaConversazioni = messageManager.getUtentiConversazioni(utente);
    messaggiNotificati = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

I left the code in Italian because it's quite simple, as it doesn't do anything "special".

What am I doing wrong? I've tried almost everything but without succeding :(

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've tried moving notificationBar's code into another page and everything works ...Things are getting quite strange ;/

Comment: just a guess , maybe it has something to do with relative path to the ./faces/messaggi.xhtml" ? which is ok on other page but not in the first one?

Comment: No, that's just a link...Still cant figure out what the problem is, but I've got it even with an empty NotificationBar

Comment: hello did you solve this problem? i got a similar behavior.... thnx

Answer (score 0):

StepTNT... I believe you need to specify filteredValue in the datatable. Normally you set a new ArrayList() instance in filteredValue but recently I face this problem and it worked for me with filteredValue without any instance.

Comment: Hello Darkness, on Stack Overflow, the best answers contain code as well as an explanation on how that code solves the problem. Anything less than that and the post may be noise. Consider an [edit] to improve this post. Good luck! :)